# .val + querySelector или .val + переменная

Tags: javascript

Как правильно вставить значение в .val по селектору, айди или классу
Или как вставить в .val переменную и как правильно её получить перед этим по селектору, айди или классу

```js
$( "input[name*='pdf-number']" ).val('Здесь должно быть данные отсюда - #main > div > div.estate-box-content > div.container > div > div.col-3 > h1');
```

id уникальный. class уникальный

Comment: `.val( $("#main h1").text() );` ?

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно